# Only iOS doesn't connect to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

Firebase connects well in android, but not in ios.

What is my problem?

below is my Xcode error messages.

```
2019-07-08 11:26:49.743456+0900 bullet3[327:12544] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2019-07-08 11:26:49.743667+0900 bullet3[327:12544] Metal API Validation Disabled
2019-07-08 11:26:50.043708+0900 bullet3[327:12544] [Warning] Trying to set delaysTouchesBegan to NO on a system gate gesture recognizer - this is unsupported and will have undesired side effects
2019-07-08 11:26:50.169842+0900 bullet3[327:12690] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-07-08 11:26:50.172212+0900 bullet3[327:12690] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2019-07-08 11:26:50.190773+0900 bullet3[327:12690]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025026] Deferring to Firebase for event data collection
2019-07-08 11:26:50.201582+0900 bullet3[327:12690] [NetworkInfo] Could not successfully update network info for descriptor <CTServiceDescriptor 0x283191d20, domain=1, instance=2> during initialization.
2019-07-08 11:26:50.203025+0900 bullet3[327:12690] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x283191d40, domain=1, instance=1>
2019-07-08 11:26:50.203389+0900 bullet3[327:12690] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x283191d20, domain=1, instance=2>
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A12 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2018.3.12f1 (8afd630d1f5b)
CrashReporter: No pending report exists at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/47A757F8-CFBD-4618-82F6-545E62BB7E22/Library/Caches/CrashReports/crash-pending.plcrash=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 327, TID: 12804, Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

for start iOS with firebase refer this link...
[Link of connect firebase with iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

You follow this link,
-> and register Your App using Bundle ID in Firebase.
-> and then follow steps and download .plist file and add in Your Project and add Client Reverse ID from this Plist file in to your Target -> select Your Project -> Info -> URL Types -> add Url -> Reverse Client ID and Bundle ID..

now You can connect your application with Firebase.